# Nodejs reading .xlsx file gives weird symbols

Tags: node.js, xlsx, fs

I'm trying to read *.xlsx file, convert it to json and write to another file.
The thing is, when i'm trying to read *.xlsx file using `fs.readFileSync` method, i'm getting weird symbols as a result. Did anybody ever faced that? how to solve it?

[image]

Code is something like this:

```js
const inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'csv/123.xlsx')

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(inputFilePath, 'utf-8')

console.log(fileContent)
```

running it with `nodemon index.js`

Comment: Use this [read-excel-file npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) or [xlsx npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReadFileSync` will always return these characters because its not a `text` file that you are reading, if you want to convert `Excel` files to `JSON`, you need to use 3rd party library like [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).

```
const xlsx= require('xlsx');

const inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'csv/123.xlsx');
let File = xlsx.readFile(inputFilePath);
let Content = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(File.Sheets[File.SheetNames[0]]);
```

This will parse `first sheet of your excel`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped!

Comment: Your solution works, but for special characters and date time, inside the table doesn't show well. do you know how it possible to visualize these?
Thanks.

Comment: @Mosen if you check the [Parsing Options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-options) on the xlsx npm page, you will see we can pass options for date parsin, check that, otherwise open a new case and we can have a look at it